# cost of Async.Start

Tags: multithreading, f#, async-await, mailboxprocessor

In a mailboxprocessor loop, I read from a blocking collection items previously stored in such collection. Since I use the same loop for writing to such collection, I need launch it as a thread.

```
async { process(queue.Take()) } |> Aysync.Start
```

The execution is of my whole code is slow (relatively speaking) and I suspect the cause is the new thread I launch, although I kickstarted the thread pool with

```
let toto = ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(300,300)
```

Another hint that the contention point might be here is that if I only launch when the queue is empty (and lock the whole section)), I have highly varying runtime, from 350 ms to 7s, while if if dont it stays around 5-10 s.

My questions are :

- is there anyway I can accelerate the creation of threads here
- are there some structure that already takes care of this kind of situation (consumer/producer ?) that can be used inside a mailboxprocessor ?

Comment: Don't guess where your performance problems are, measure it! You can use a profiler to do that.

Comment: very good point. I am also a hard believer of measuring first and optimize later, I guess I should apply it. can you transfer it to an answer ?  (since I discover the dotnet + fsharp stuff I have little knowledge of good tools to do the profiling... any recommendation appreciated)

Comment: @nicolas - why so many threads.  I suspect that you will find things faster at around 20 threads (even less if you are CPU bound)

Comment: in my case I am IO bounded. I did not know about SetMinThreads before yesterday (if i exclude everything I knew before 5 years ago :) ) and encountered a case where it was the source of slowness, so who knows..

Comment: I think svick has a strong point : before optimizing, one ought to measure. it might just be some effing slowness in the IO system I call. I have computation running from 400 ms to 20s. so my question is ill posed in the first place.

Comment: Can someone point out what the `process` keyword does in the example?  Googling didn't reveal anything apart from VS2010 F# keyword reference stating `process` being reserved for future expansion. Is it something new in VS11?

Comment: hi @KomradeP. this is not a keyword, was meant to be a placeholder for saying someprocess. I recommend the asynchronous blocking queue agent from Tomas for the purpose. My inexperience with the mailboxprocessor made me rewrite the thing with threads, but Mailboxboxprocessor is a perfect fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create hundreds of threads to run an I/O bound computation then there is probably something wrong. If a computation is I/O bound then it should be possible to run it using relatively small number of threads - if it is fully *asynchronous* it means that the threads will not be blocked during any waiting.

So, I think the first thing to look for in your program are places where a thread is blocked and replace that with waiting that is asynchronous.

One suspicious thing in your code sample is the queue, which is probably blocking when you call `Take`, at least, that's how [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) in .NET behaves. You can try replacing that with [`BlockingQueueAgent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297096.aspx), which implements the same functionality using F# agents but provides asynchronous `AsyncTake` method that can be called without blocking a thread.

Comment: I seem to have reimplemented BlockingQueueAgent. which was not so straightforward. at least I learned a lot.

Comment: indeed reducing the number of thread add no impact. at the time i set it i was indeed seeing the effect of a too small pool (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955960/cost-of-runsynchronously) so set it to some high number. Here reducing it has little impact, so the 'pb' is elsewhere. Beside your helpful hint at BlockingQueueAgent, which tool would you recommend for measuring first, and optimizing later ?

Comment: tomas, I hope you feel sorry for me for reimplemeting a mailboxagent using threads and old knowledge about them and completely ignoring your finely minimalistically crafted mailboxagent.